# Form Events in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to learn C# and I am having a doubt in adding the control to the Form. objects like button has many events associated with it. But the events are not listed as in Visual Basic. Is there any method to view all events associated with an object in C#

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Events button in the Properties window?  It will show you a list of the events subscribed via the designer.

Comment: Read the documents, eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#events

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: use Visual Studio man. Drag and Drop and double-clicking the control will automate the event method.

Comment: Thank u i did it